# jaxb.index and nested classes (and OSGi)

Tags: java, jaxb

When I try to refer to nested classes within my jaxb.index file, an exception is thrown during serialization. How can this be avoided?

This is in an Eclipse RCP application. The classes causing the exception are in a different plug-in than the one that creates the JAXB context and initiates serialization. The classes are in one of the plug-in's exported packages.

The class structure looks like this (names have been changed):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="foo")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
   ...
    @XmlRootElement(name="fooMetric")
    @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class FooMetric implements IFooMetric {
        ...
    }
}
```

The jaxb.index file contains these:

```
Foo
Foo.FooMetric
```

During serialization, the exception says to use "OuterClass.InnerClass" -- which I'm doing.

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: error loading class "Foo.FooMetric" listed in com/mypackage/jaxb.index, make sure that entries are accessable on CLASSPATH and of the form "ClassName" or "OuterClass.InnerClass", not "ClassName.class" or "fully.qualified.ClassName"
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.Foo.FooMetric]

The javadocs (["Format for jaxb.index"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)) also suggests that jaxb.index can contain entries of the form OuterClass.InnerClass.

> Constraints on class name occuring in a jaxb.index file are:
>
> - Must not end with ".class".
> - Class names are resolved relative to package containing jaxb.index file. Only classes occuring directly in package containing jaxb.index file are allowed.
> - Fully qualified class names are not allowed. A qualified class name,relative to current package, is only allowed to specify a nested or inner class.

However, this does not appear to work. What will make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found (by trial and error) was to use `OuterClass$InnerClass` in jaxb.index instead of `OuterClass.InnerClass`. This allows serialization to complete successfully.

However, I haven't found any authoritative source that recommends this.

[I'm posting this solution per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but would love to see and accept a better answer.]

Comment: I'm looking for the official documentation on this.  The `$` separator is what is currently supported by both the JAXB reference implementation and EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).

Comment: Thank you. After seeing your blog and stackoverflow posts, I was hoping you would comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

For those using camel-jaxb (2.21.1 on my side) having a similar issue, it seams that that neither using `OuterClass$InnerClass`, nor `OuterClass.InnerClass` works.
Even though the exception suggests the latter should work:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: 
Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[direct:xxx]] -> [OnException[[class java... 
because of Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: 
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: error loading class "IdentifierListSearchRequestType.IdentifierSearch" 
listed in com/.../jaxb.index, 
make sure that entries are accessable on CLASSPATH and of the form "ClassName" or "OuterClass.InnerClass", 
not "ClassName.class" or "fully.qualified.ClassName"
```

The only solution I found was to extract inner classes in their own file and set the `@XmlType` name accordingly instead of leaving it blank